# action load more than once by TCpdf in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, tcpdf

i'm working with Tcpdf in Yii framework , (just)when i created new Tcpdf in my view to export a file , this caused my action load two or three times (i had checked it by a counter in my action) and finally it worked and give me my pdf file .

i don't want this action load several times because in action i'm changing some attributes by some rules and this rules will changes after first time that controller had loaded.

this problem is in host and in my local(xammp) this work correctly (my server is linux )

my action :

```
public function actionPrint_diploma($id)
{
    // check number of load this action :
    if(isset(Yii::app()->session['counter'])&&Yii::app()->session['counter']>=0)
        Yii::app()->session['counter']=Yii::app()->session['counter']+1;
    else    
        Yii::app()->session['counter']=0;

    // ...

    $this->render('coach_certificate');

}
```

my view (coach_certificate.php):

```
// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
$dir=Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/my_library/tcpdf/examples/tcpdf_include.php';

require_once($dir);

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetTitle('printing certificate');
$pdf->SetSubject('printing certificate');
$pdf->SetKeywords('PDF');

// remove default header/footer
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);


// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 061', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
//$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(FALSE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);


// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/far.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/far.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

//$pdf->addTTFfont('/fonts/BZar.ttf', '', '', 32);
// ---------------------------------------------------------
// set font                                                          
$lg = Array();
$lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$lg['a_meta_dir'] = 'rtl';
$lg['a_meta_language'] = 'fa';
$lg['w_page'] = 'page';

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
$pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);

// ---------------------------------------------------------


$pdf->AddPage();                                                                                                                 

$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 10);   

$pdf->SetAbsXY(305,50);
$html = Yii::app()->session['counter'];
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, true,'C');    

$pdf->lastPage();                                                                        

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output("test.pdf", 'D');                                         // 
Yii::app()->end();
```

Comment: You can use a flag in the session same way you have set the counter and only run the code if flag is not set etc..

Comment: @Manquer , i had used this but the problem of this way is that where i can change the flag after the flag is true ?

Comment: `if(isset(Yii::app()->session['myFlag']) && Yii::app()->session['myFlag'] !== true) { Yii::app()->session['myFlag'] = true; // do action logic ;  Yii::app()->session['myFlag'] = false; Yii::app()->end()  }`

Comment: @Manquer this not work , because i will change an attribute of model with a rule(the rule is related to that attribute )

Comment: if($model->is_print==0) { $message='not printed'; $model->is_print=1 ; model->save() ; } else {  $message='printed'; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use two action to solve this problem.!

**step 1 :**

In the first action set your changes etc ... Then don't use from `render` and instead of it, use `redirect` to **second action** .

**step 2 :**

In the second action just `render` your view file.
finally if it several time load action, it load second action and doesn't call your change functions for several times.
i hope it work's correctly

Enjoy it ;-)